# how to get this regular expression pattern to work from javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

So it says this question below is a bad question because it has bad syntax...which I wouldn't have figured out if I didn't ask it, so not sure why this counts against me for possibly not enabling me to ask questions.  So I click delete and it won't let me delete the question either.  So what am I supposed to do?

I have a regular expression which allows special characters with the exception of < and > in the input and from html and it works like so:

```
<input type="text" name="logoName[]" class="modal-text" placeholder="Name" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&amp;*()_+/\-=,.;:'/\?/\//\\ ]+">
```

In other places, I need to write this pattern from javascript and visual studio code doesn't like it one bit:

```
const regexPattern = '^[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*()_+/\\-=,.;:'/\?/\//\\ ]+';
```

I also tried:

```
  function escapeRegex(string) {
    string = string.toString();
    return string.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
  }
const regexPattern = escapeRegex(/^[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*()_+/\-=,.;:'/\?/\//\\ ]+/g);
```

and no luck with that method either.
Can someone please help? When it comes to regular expressions I'm not very good, I've tried all sorts of ways of escaping but I'm not grasping it.  thanks.

Comment: `const regexPattern = '^[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*()_+/\\-=,.;:'/\?/\//\\ ]+';` is basically a syntax error because you are prematurelly closing the string by using `'` in the string value itself. Either escape the character(`\'`) or enclose the whole string in double quotes instead of single ones.

Comment: Yes you are right, I think that was my main problem, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a free formatter online tool and this below works for me, I think the single quotes were messing me up too:

```
const regexPattern = "^[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&amp;*()_+\/\\-=,.;:'\/\\?\/\\\/\/\\\\ ]+";
```